# Renting an office: Landlord wants to rent out a small adjoining office separately

Tags: office-layout

Got a dilemma at the mo. I rent a good sized office which has a smaller adjoining office just to the side after you enter my office. So need to go through the main door which is the only door into my office, and then there is this small office which has its own door to the side.

Another tenant had been previously renting it but was never there so there was no issue. Now that tenant has left and the landlord wants to rent it out again.

I want to be easy going but at the same time I am not happy with a stranger or another person/company walking in and out of my office.

Do I have to agree here or what is the best solution for me? I could rent it myself but it would cost me too much but at the same time I am not sure I want the trouble of telling them they can't enter my private office in order to enter the other smaller room.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with navigating the workplace, it is asking whether a tenant has a say in deciding to whom a landlord should rent out their property.

Comment: The room belongs to the landlord, he can do what he pleases there. Your rental agreement should make it clear whether the landlord is allowed to use part of the property rented to you for "transit" to his other property.

Comment: The landlord can rent their offices to whomever they like - I just don't think I have to agree when it requires entering my privately rented space. But yes, this q may be too much off topic which I have just realised.

Comment: This is a legal question - your first step is to check you tenancy agreement to make sure it doesn't specifically state you have to allow common access, next step is try to negotiate a lockable internal door between your space the other office, third is talk with a lawyer about options (if step 2 doesn't work out).

Comment: Yes, that is what I am going to do. There isnt anything about common access in the lease, but the landlord had previously agreed to making a new door for this other office, but then called to say they had changed their mind as it would make it less attractive to companies to rent out. Not sure if they are bluffing about having other interested parties to force me to pay it myself. Another lesson learned here for the future!

Comment: Yes, via email, but through their secretary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to agree here or what is the best solution for me?

I'd negotiate my rent downwards. The landlord owns both rooms, but I pay for exclusive use of one. If I have to share that use then I want a rent drop. Alternative is the Landlord makes another entry for the other room. This is what is normally done, each place you rent should have it's own ingress/egress.

A shared emergency exit is not great, but understandable. But don't pay premium rent for substandard conditions.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Money and rep, good tenants don't grow on trees. And new tenants are sometimes a gamble if you can actually find them,

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yep, they'd be silly to do that in a good rental market locale. Perhaps on renewal time.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere That's the answer I'd pick. Mine isn't really a very good answer.

Comment: I agreed on the basis that they would be making a temporary entrance but I was distracted and easy going about it. They emailed later to say the current tenant had agreed to this new entrance, but didnt do it. I had just let it go. I found a friend who needs a spot and can reliably trust them so I will probably just do it that way 

Comment: The building is being demolished early next year. Won't be renewing with them when they move location.